# Looping a code-chunk in LaTeX

Tags: sweave, knitr

I want to generate a report for three types of analysis I am performing. But each time when I perform the analysis it can happen that one or more than one type of analysis occur. I want to put condition in the report that will run the part of report according to the type of analysis performed. For each analysis I need to repeat the chunk say n times. I am stuck at writing a for loop for the code chunk.
'a' is a vector
eg code:

```
\myboolean\Sexpr{myboolean}
for(i in 1:n)
\section{Frequency Analysis}
<<for-loop>>=
print(a[i])
@
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish, but have a look at either tikz/pgf or luatex, both have for-loops.

Answer (score 2):

See https://gist.github.com/3145751 for an example with `knitr`. You cannot insert LaTeX into R code directly (it is not like PHP), but you can knit a child document for n times with different values of `i`.

Comment: I'm not able to run your example. When I am running the code a .tex file gets generated but fails to give a pdf document. I have attached the log file and the .tex file along.

Comment: Error: running 'texi2dvi' on 'temp.tex' failed
LaTeX errors:
:1: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
:1: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
:14: LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
:16: LaTeX Error: Command \hlnumber already defined.
Or name \end... illegal,
:17: LaTeX Error: Command \hlfunctioncall already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, 
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:\PROGRA~1\Miktex\miktex\bin\texi2dvi.exe" --quiet --pdf "temp.tex"  -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-214~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-214~1.2/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1

Comment: Inorder to save space I have removed- 
**:See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help**

Comment: could you paste the log somewhere like pastebin? http://pastebin.com/ I cannot really read the log here. BTW, are you using the latest version of `knitr`?

Comment: After using the latest knitr package I was able to get a pdf file but there were following problems with them.
**i.** when I use **knit2pdf** no pdf is generated and here is the link to log-file [link](http://pastebin.com/WyfP5dTe)
**ii.** when I use compile pdf tab a pdf is generated with only one file(Now i is 1) in it along with some text **articlegraphicx, color upqoute framed alltt alltt** I understand these are the package names, but dont know why they are printed in the pdf. [link](http://pastebin.com/QrDAUCfJ)

Comment: **iii.** Also when I use echo= FALSE in the parent file in code chunk **run-all** compile pdf tab the output is same as the one described in _ii._ point but with different errors,log file [link](http://pastebin.com/yLnXM29x)

Comment: I have solved the issue by creating a template of .Rnw file in brew. Using conditions and loops I was able to replicate certain code chunks. Here's the link to example code: [link](http://pastebin.com/bKkxxJqj) 
I run the command brew('test.brew', 'output.rnw') to get a rnw file and then compile it to pdf.